# A lot of terms to calculate lim

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prepare for exam and I came across a limit to calculate.

$$
\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{2^n + \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^3} + \dfrac {4^n}{n^4}}{\dfrac {4^n}{n^4} + n^3\cdot 3^n}
$$

When I'm trying to extract $4^n$ I end up with nothing. 
And I managed to tell that $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^3}$ goes to infinity, bounding it with $2$ and $3$. Cause I know that $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}$ goes to $e$ as $n$ is increasing.

I'd appreciate some help or tips on that one, cause I'm stuck with it for over an hour and I couldn't find any clues how to solve it on-line.

Chris

Comment: You're on the right track.  If that one term approaches $e$, then can you say anything about the limit of that term if you have $n^3$ rather than $n^2$ in the exponent?  Do any of the other terms clearly dominate the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{2^n + e^n + \frac{4^n}{n^4}}{\frac{4^n}{n^4} + 3^nn^3} = \frac{2^nn^4 + e^nn^4 + 4^n}{4^n + n^73^n} = \frac{\frac{n^4}{2^n} + (\frac{e}{4})^n\cdot n^4 + 1}{1 + (\frac{3}{4})^nn^7} $$

Now, since $a^n$ is an infinite of magnitude greater than $n^b$ for all $b$, we conclude that all those fractions tends to zero (cause also $a^n$ tends to zero really fast if $a < 1$) that leaves you with $1$ both at the numerator and the denominator

So the limit is $1$

Comment: Thank you... Why didnt i think about extracting $\frac{4^n}{n^4}$

Comment: you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A bit (very) fast and loose but multiply by one AKA $\displaystyle \frac{n^4}{n^4}$ to get

$$
\begin{align}\frac{n^4(2^n+e^n)+4^n}{4^n+n^73^n}&=\frac{n^4(2^n+e^n)}{4^n+n^73^n}+\frac{4^n}{4^n+n^73^n}\\&=\frac{n^4(2^n+e^n)}{4^n+n^73^n}+\frac{1}{1+n^7\cdot(\frac34)^n}
\\&\approx\frac{n^4e^n}{4^n}+1
\\&\approx 1.
\end{align}$$

for $n$ large.

i.e. $4^n$ is the Daddy here.

Comment: Thanks for nice approach :)